# Atheros AR9285 patched driver

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, atheros

I am new to ubuntu and I have a problem installing patched drivers for my atheros AR9285 wireless adapter.
Where can I find drivers which support injection?
please help.
thank you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I would strongly suggest using the [Compat Drivers](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/compat-drivers) Latest releases are available that might support packet injection, and the irc can give you excellent support if you need to apply patches.